# SQL Server stored procedure not in plan cache nor Profiler

Tags: sql-server, caching, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I'm having trouble determining why a certain stored procedure does not appear in the plan cache nor SQL Server Profiler. I'm running SQL Server 2014 SP2.

The stored procedure and the type are shown below. The only reference I found that might have been useful spoke of a bug fix in SS 2008 where a blob was used in a string function. I do have a blob (`ntext`) in the type definition. Could this be the cause or related in some way? If not, what else could cause this behavior? Is there any way to get the stored procedure to be cache and/or display in the profiler?

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[OruMessages] AS TABLE
(
    [msg_status] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [msg_no] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [HL7_text_long] [ntext] NULL,
    [HL7_text_short] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [patient_id] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [msh_system] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [msh_organization] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [msh_event_cd] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [msh_msg_type] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [sent_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [queued_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages]
    (@messageList [dbo].[OruMessages] READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[HL7_out_queue]
    SELECT
        [msg_status],
        [msg_no],
        [HL7_text_long],
        [HL7_text_short],
        [patient_id],
        [msh_system],
        [msh_organization],
        [msh_event_cd],
        [msh_msg_type],
        [sent_dt],
        [queued_dt]
    FROM
        @messageList;
END;
GO


CREATE EVENT SESSION [Capture [usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages]] executions] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_end(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'db' AND [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages%'))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_start(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[database_name]=N'db' AND [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages%'))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[equal_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[database_name],N'db') AND [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages%') )),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[equal_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[database_name],N'db') AND [sqlserver].[like_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[sql_text],N'%usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages%') ))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\db\Capture [usp_HL7_SaveOruMessages] executions')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Comment: Can you change the table type to use an nVarChar(max) instead of an nText value? nText is years out of date, and I would wager that field is as likely as anything to be causing this issue.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I was finally able to update the TYPE as NVARCHAR(MAX).  I still cannot see the stored procedure execution in my extended events session.

Comment: I finally altered the Extended Events session to give me all the RPC, Batch and module calls from the host machine and was able to find the SP in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final altered Extended Events session to give me all the RPC, Batch and module calls from the host machine and I was then able to find the stored procedure in question.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [<MachineName>] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[client_hostname]=N'<MachineName>')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[client_hostname]=N'<MachineName>')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[client_hostname]=N'<MachineName>'))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\ExtEvents\<MachineName>.xel',max_file_size=(5120))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
```